# Getting MVP Status - What have you (MVPs) have done to get it?

Tags: discussion, mvp

I know that there is a document like https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/mvp/ which describes how you could achieve MVP status, but it lacks the part how you got the knowledge and the experience to be able to assist/help other users.

Therefore i would like to ask how you have gotten that experience/knowledge if you have not been working for Salesforce or an Salesforce partner. I believe it is very hard to get knowledge that is normally being hidden from "normal" users. With normal documentation you won't possibly achieve it because it lacks detailed knowledge and only covers the surface.

Since the company where i am working only has one product (Marketing Cloud) licensed, i am not certain if you could ever reach MVP Status when you won't be able to answer questions which cover integration from X (Sales Cloud / CRM / DMP ...) to Marketing Cloud. On the other hand i do not know how many MVPs are being chosen/nominated. If only two / three would get this status it would be very hard to surpass guys like Eliot Harper or Adam Spriggs (who definitely deserve it)

I personally would like to heavily invest into predictive web / mail  and Marketing Cloud in general. But especially predictive web knowledge (which is one of the newest products of Salesforce) can only be obtained through very cost intensive usage of engagement teams, because supports mostly cannot answer or redirects to production teams where answers take very long.

Do you have any advice how to proceed to reach an aim like the one i have described above? Feel free to add stuff which i didn't ask but suit the general idea ;)

Comment: Before getting too hung up on this ambition, do understand that there is quite an element of marketing involved in the programme. The MVP status for the individual helps their career, and having the MVPs market Salesforce helps Salesforce. See Samuel's comment that influence about the products is not directly correlated to MVP status.

Answer (score 21):

Johannes

There is no clear track to MVP status, as there are many ways to get recognised as such. Be it officially by salesforce, or the times before that in the hearts and minds of the people in the communities you're active in, engaging in and sharing in. It's definitely not a contest, it's much like life itself: care for others and you'll feel rewarded, but please don't do it for the recognition.

The MVP program page you've linked lists four characteristics that are evaluated during the nomination process: knowledge, generosity, advocacy and leadership. I'd argue that knowledge is the least relevant, none of us know the same things or have the same experiences. This creates ample opportunity to share what you do know and have learnt, share your knowledge, or facilitate others sharing their knowledge. Many of the (separate yet intertwined) communities in the salesforce ecosystem are exactly based around that, learning from others, and sharing your experiences too. (and the occasional venting).

I've personally had the fortune to meet and talk with an lot of current and past MVPs and can only testify they usually have those 4 characteristics and a fifth: passion. But most never set out to become an MVP, they set out to interact and help, smoothen the path to learning salesforce and keep up with it, as a group, as a community.

Salesforce.stackexchange has become one of these communities, and for several MVPs, it have been their interactions here that have played a role, in itself or in combination with other communication channels or communities where they are active. Quite a number of MVPs also organise or actively participate in their local user groups, community or salesforce events, maintain blogs, guest-blog, do podcasts, volunteer or find other ways to combine their interest in salesforce, sharing and finding meaning in doing so.

Thank you for being part of our community :-)

Comment: Great comment Samuel. Personally i believe passion is a must have. But if you seek knowledge and you know there is a fence to this knowledge you become somewhat frustrated. MVPs have access to product and marketing teams of salesforce which nobody else is given(AFAIK). I am really seeking out to these opportunities because there is so much that i want to ask [and improve] where nobody is currently able to answer or listen (idea exchange is bad for predictive because nobody does even vote there). Example for this is that i currently have 6 open support cases that list development mistakes (POV)

Comment: Honestly, those that have greater access to product management do not have that because they are MVPs. But because they are passionate, yet critical about the product and voice strong arguments and clear communication. Potentially in combination with frequently visiting some of the same conferences as where product management members may be found. (AFAIK)

Comment: Usually the people which can be found in conferences do not know about the predictive intelligence of marketing cloud [new product, has to much development background, ...] even elliot said he doesn't know much about this topic when i asked him on january 2018. When he does not then i really do not believe they will send out persons like personalization builder / predictive intelligence developers  to conferences held in europe[where i am located] who know more than him. I do not see a different chance then asking support and darryl brown in collaboration, but its a very very slow process.

Comment: Hello @JohannesSchapdick, I'd be happy to discuss the MVP program further and give a few suggestions in how to approach nomination. I can meet up at DF18 or you can schedule a call at eliot.com.au. As Samuel explained, it's generally not awarded based on one single contribution (e.g. SFSE participation) although there are some exceptions of exceptional individuals. Regarding your comment on my PI knowledge, I've spent a lot of time on this over the past months and now consider my PI knowledge to be very comprehensive and I've delivered many PI courses across the globe this year :-)

Comment: regarding access, I would just be happy being able to report and work on a real bug rather than just let it go and wait for it to be fixed - Oh wait, that was venting.....